# How to update responsive AdSense ad using React without refreshing site

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive-design, responsive, adsense

I'm trying to add an AdSense responsive ad to my React web app. I created an AdComponent by following AdSense Help's [Exact ad unit size per screen width example](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9183363#exact):

```js
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

class AdComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    (window.adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <CustomIns
        className="adsbygoogle"
        style={{ display: 'inline-block' }}
        data-ad-client="ca-pub-5555444121816745"
        data-ad-slot="2476129802"
      />
    );
  }
}

export default AdComponent;

const CustomIns = styled.ins`
  width: 320px;
  height: 100px;

  @media (min-width: 500px) {
    width: 468px;
    height: 60px;
  }

  @media (min-width: 800px) {
    width: 728px;
    height: 90px;
  }
`;
```

Whenever the website loads, a perfect sized ad is displayed, but when I resize (or rotate) the screen, the ad stays with the same initial size. The expected behavior is that whenever I hit a breakpoint, the ad is replaced for a resized one that fits in the new dimensions.

Comment: AdSense should detect screen rotation and resize slot correspondingly while requesting new ad. For example try http://nbeloglazov.com/adsense.html with mobile emulation and rotate it - you'll see ad refreshed and resized. Are you saying that when you rotate screen the ad doesn't change?

Answer (score 0):

This can not be done using specific width and height like you are using. Ones a screen is loaded, the ad unit for that screen width is loaded with it. If you then rotate the screen, the same ad will keep showing.

What you want is 'responsive ads'. use the following code and you will see it works out for you.

```
  style="display:block"
  data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  data-ad-slot="xxxxxxxxxx"
  data-ad-format="auto">
```

I see in you code that you use only horizontal banners. If you can only use horizontal. You can use the following:

```
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
     data-ad-slot="xxxxxxxxxx"
     data-ad-format="horizontal"
data-full-width-responsive="false"></ins>
```

This gives you only horizontal ad units that are fitted in the screen size.
More options and ad sizes [link here](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9183460?hl=en)